# Looping in Snowflake SQL without UDFs

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake SQL, I am trying to achieve a scenario to create array aggreagate of dates based on certain where conditions, but I am not able to achieve it.

For instance, below is the input data i have.

| DATE | DATE_15_DAYS_BEFORE | PREV_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-09-13 | 2023-08-29 | 2023-08-21 |
| 2023-09-19 | 2023-09-04 | 2023-09-13 |
| 2023-09-27 | 2023-09-12 | 2023-09-19 |
| 2023-10-05 | 2023-09-20 | 2023-09-27 |

So when DATE_15_DAYS_BEFORE is smaller than PREV_DATE then we need to create an array aggregate of dates between DATE_15_DAYS_BEFORE and DATE.

For example, above we date_15_dayas_before as 2023-09-04 which is smaller than 2023-09-13 then the next column should have array agg as ['2023-09-04', '2023-09-19'].

**Expected Output**

| DATE | DATE_15_DAYS_BEFORE | PREV_DATE | ARRAG_AGG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-09-13 | 2023-08-29 | 2023-08-21 | [] |
| 2023-09-19 | 2023-09-04 | 2023-09-13 | ['2023-09-13', '2023-09-19'] |
| 2023-09-27 | 2023-09-12 | 2023-09-19 | ['2023-09-13', '2023-09-19', '2023-09-27'] |
| 2023-10-05 | 2023-09-20 | 2023-09-27 | ['2023-09-20', '2023-09-27', '2023-10-05'] |

Could any one help me achieving this scenario using snowflake SQL without using stored procedures and UDFs ?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why have you tagged mysql and SQL server???

Comment: In your expected output, should the last row ARRAY_AGG be `['2023-09-20', '2023-09-27', '2023-10-05']`?

Comment: Hi @Teej, yes, sorry my bad

Comment: why is `09-04` in the second row's output, but third rows value of `09-12` not it that rows output. You seem to have values from both `date` and `date_15_days_before` and `prev-date`

Comment: Hi @SimeonPilgrim, sorry there was a typo, second row should not have 09-04. Your first  option in answer solves my issue. Thanks a ton for your help and i am extremely sorry for the confusion in question. I have updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You logic as described is inconsistent.

One way to look at it is aggregate only the values in the `date` column if two rules apply.

1. `date_15_days_before` is less than `prev_date`
2. the `date` is between `date_15_days_before` and `date`

thus that could look like in SQL:

```
with data(date, date_15_days_before, prev_date) as (
    select * from values
        ('2023-09-13'::date, '2023-08-29'::date, '2023-08-21'::date),
        ('2023-09-19'::date, '2023-09-04'::date, '2023-09-13'::date),
        ('2023-09-27'::date, '2023-09-12'::date, '2023-09-19'::date),
        ('2023-10-05'::date, '2023-09-20'::date, '2023-09-27'::date)
)
select
    d1.*,
    array_agg(iff(d1.date_15_days_before < d1.prev_date, 
        iff(d2.date between d1.date_15_days_before and d1.date, d2.date, null),
        null
        )) as array_agg
from data as d1
cross join data as d2
group by 1,2,3
order by 1;
```

and give:

[image]

but the second row of your "expected output" has a `2023-09-04` value in to, which implies, you are also adding the values from the `date_15_days_before` column. *BUT* why does row three not have `2023-09-12` in the output then?

so the second one can be done as:

```
with data(date, date_15_days_before, prev_date) as (
    select * from values
        ('2023-09-13'::date, '2023-08-29'::date, '2023-08-21'::date),
        ('2023-09-19'::date, '2023-09-04'::date, '2023-09-13'::date),
        ('2023-09-27'::date, '2023-09-12'::date, '2023-09-19'::date),
        ('2023-10-05'::date, '2023-09-20'::date, '2023-09-27'::date)
)
select
    d1.*,
    iff(d1.date_15_days_before < d1.prev_date,
        array_sort(array_distinct(array_append(
            array_agg(iff(d1.date_15_days_before < d1.prev_date, 
                iff(d2.date between d1.date_15_days_before and d1.date, d2.date, null),
                null
            ))
        , d1.date_15_days_before))),
        [] 
        )as option_2
from data as d1
cross join data as d2
group by 1,2,3
order by 1;
```

but there is the 12th of Sep in the results:

[image]